# Android: first element of a GridView is misplaced in galaxy S3 and S4

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm building an app that has a mini slotMachine game inside. The problem is that I use a GridView for each column of the slot and for some devices (not all) the first symbol of the slot has a space above that comes from nowhere...

The table of the slot is 3 rows X 5 columns.

The space doesn't come from the calculation of the symbol width and height because I've found that with two devices withe perfectly identical resolution and density (Galaxy tab 10.1 and Galaxy note 10.1) the spacing is different: 0 for one and 5 for the other.

Any help?

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    SlotView slot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        slot=new SlotView(this);
        slot.refreshSlotView("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");       

    }
}
```

SlotView:

```
public class SlotView {
    private ArrayList<GridAdapter> adapter=new ArrayList<GridAdapter>();
    public float H_RATIO=2/3; //height ratio of the grid based on the device
    public float W_RATIO=5/6; //width ratio of the grid based on the device

    Activity activity;

    String path = "file:///android_asset/Slot/Slot-";

    public SlotView(Context c){
        activity = (Activity) c;

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        final int hDisplay=dm.heightPixels;
        int wImage=(1024*hDisplay)/768; //width of the central image
        float heightGrid=(hDisplay*2)/3; //grid height
        float widthGrid=((wImage*5)/6); //grid width

        float heightSymbol=(heightGrid-(8))/3; // symbol height (3 symbols for column with a spacing of 4 px)

        //relative layout for the container table
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)widthGrid, (int)heightGrid);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        // grid of the slot
        LinearLayout grid_layout=(LinearLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.layout_grid);
        grid_layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        grid_layout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

        // gridview of the columns 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_grid=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)heightSymbol, (int)heightGrid);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ // five columns
            GridView slot=new GridView(activity);
            slot.setScrollContainer(false);
            slot.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            slot.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            if(i<4) {
                params_grid.setMargins(0,0,4,0); // spacing between each column
            }
            slot.setLayoutParams(params_grid);
            slot.setVerticalSpacing(4);
            slot.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            slot.setColumnWidth((int)heightSymbol);
            slot.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);  
            slot.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            GridAdapter grid_adapter=new GridAdapter(activity, (int)heightSymbol, (int)heightSymbol);
            adapter.add(grid_adapter);
            slot.setAdapter(grid_adapter);  
            grid_layout.addView(slot);
        }
    }

    public void refreshSlotView(String configTris){
        for(int pos=0; pos<5; pos++){
            String[] mThumbIds=new String[3];
            int z=0;
            for(int i=pos; z<3 && i<configTris.length(); i=i+5){

                char letter=configTris.charAt(i);   

                mThumbIds[z]=path + letter + ".png";
                z++;
            }
            adapter.get(pos).setArrayOfImage(mThumbIds);
            adapter.get(pos).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The adapter:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mThumbIds={};
    private int w;
    private int h;

    public GridAdapter(Context c, int w, int h) {
        mContext = c;
        this.w=w;
        this.h=h;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=convertView;
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slot_element, null);
            RelativeLayout rel=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rel);
            rel.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(w, h));

            imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w, h);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }else{
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).into(imageView); // puts the image in the imageview
        return view;
    }
    public void setArrayOfImage(String[] images){
        this.mThumbIds=images;
    }

    public void showSymbolAtIndex(char letter, int position){

        mThumbIds[position]="file:///android_asset/" + "Slot/Slot-" + letter + ".png";
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the slot_element Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now that's the result:
[image: first image]

And that's the proof of the existing spacing (if I drag one of the columns up):
[image: second image]